# count the average line length in a document

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i try with beautifull soup to calculate the average line length of document but i realize that it is not simple

I have tried something like that and i have got weird result

```
self.average_line_length = np.mean([ len(br.text) for br in self.contents.find_all('br')])
```

when i check the result like:

```
for s1 in my_doc.contents.find_all(re.compile('br')) :
    print s1,len(s1)
```

Results :

```
<br> does not contain any document with the entity or if our practition-
<br> er has only selected a verbal descriptor of the compound not used 
<br> within  the  documents.  In  fact,  a  query  on  ‘</br></br></br></br> **252**
```

normally it has to be :

```
<br> does not contain any document with the entity or if our practition- **68**
<br> er has only selected a verbal descriptor of the compound not used **66**
<br> within  the  documents.  In  fact,  a  qu
```

‘

Answer (score 0):

According to your result, your html actually is like below:

```
....
<br> 
    does not contain any document with the entity or if our practition-
    <br> er has only selected a verbal descriptor of the compound not used 
        <br> within  the  documents.  In  fact,  a  query  on  ‘
        </br>
    </br>
</br>
....
```

See? Nested br elements.

BeautifulSoup finds the three nested br elements. And as your code print, the first one in find_all's result is the outermost 'br',which contains two inner brs. and its text attribute is:

> does not contain any document with the entity or if our practition-
>    er has only selected a verbal descriptor of the compound not used 
>    within  the  documents.  In  fact,  a  query  on  ‘